# How to access its object query properties I know it have 5 properties in it

Tags: python, django, orm

I wanna access `<QuerySet [<User: xyz>]>` this object properties it have multiple properties but i dont know how to access each property and update its value

```
u = User.objects.filter(username=username)
u.first_name=(str(first_name))
u.save(`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either iterate through the instances in the queryset, and interact with them accordingly:

```
for u in User.objects.filter(username=username):
    print(u.first_name)  # Access & print `first_name`
    u.first_name=first_name # Update `first_name`
    u.save()  # Need to save the changes
```

or, you can use `update` to change all the instances in the queryset at once:

```
User.objects.filter(username=username).update(first_name=first_name)
```

You could also get `first_name` as a list if all you want is the first names for some reason:

```
User.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('first_name', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

User.objects.filter() returns list of results. In your example, "u" is a list of users. Can be list with one user.

To be able to modify user's properties, you have to take a QuerySet.

**filter**

```
list_of_users = User.objects.filter(username='username')
if list_of_users:
    #  lets say I will take first one.
    user = list_of_users[0]
    user.username = "new name"
    user.level = "new level"
    #  etc.
    user.save()
```

**get**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

name = "username"
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=name)
    user.username = "new username"
    user.level = "new level"
    #  etc
    user.save()
except User.DoesNotExist:
    LOGGER.info("User with given name %s does not exist", name)
```